# Insert code before the_content (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Currently I'm developing a gallery plugin for Wordpress, and I would like to give my users the option to choose the gallery's position (before or after the_content).

Currently, I have succeeded to put it after the content, by hooking into the_content like this:

```
function add_post_content($content) {

    if ( 'gallery' == get_post_type() && is_single() ) {

        $content .= gallery_frontend();
        $content .= gallery_map_display();

    }

    if ( 'gallery' == get_post_type() && is_archive() ) {

        // archive functions here    

    }

    return $content;

}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

Is there any way to get it to display before the_content in stead of after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just concatenate in the other direction?

```
$content = gallery_frontend() . gallery_map_display() . $content;
```

I am not sure what your functions do, but if they just return string data then this should work fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Thanks m8, works like a charm! Sometimes it's just weird how simple it can be  :-)

Comment: Great, so does that answer your question?